# problems with installation of beautifulsoup 4.6 for python 3.6 on mac

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm having trouble installing beautifulsoup 4.6 for python 3.6 on my 2012 macbook air. For some reason beautiulsoup works just fine on python 2.7 which comes preinstalled in the mac, however when I try to use/install it for python 3.6 it simply won't do it. Is there any way i can bypass the builtin python 2.7, and install the package for 3.6?

Below is a picture of the error message in Python 3.6 when I try to run the code

```
>>> from bs4 import beautifulsoup
```

[picture of the error message in python 3.6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOd1U.png)

Comment: You haven't given any of the relevant information. Did you try and install it for 3.6? How?

Answer (score 0):

just install it for python3

`pip3 install bs4`

if that didn't work then you should provide more info.

Comment: Okay, so I figured there was a problem with BeautifulSoup where it hadn't changed it's code from python 2 to python 3(i got that fixed), and it runs just fine in terminal. However when i Try to run the same code in PyCharm it gives an error saying "from html.parser import (HTMLParser,HTMLParseError)
ImportError: cannot import name 'HTMLParseError'", and a couple more. Why is this?

Comment: did you changed the project interpreter?

Comment: check [Configuring Python Interpreter for a Project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter-for-a-project.html) out.

Comment: Alright, so I ended up making a whole new project in PyCharm and it runs fine on Python3.6 however the terminal still doesn't want to run the simple "import bs4" command on python3.6 (but does it on 2.7). On terminal i used --> python3 -->import bs4

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .builder import builder_registry
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bs4/builder/__init__.py", line 294, in <module>
    from . import _htmlparser
  File

Comment: "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bs4/builder/_htmlparser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from html.parser import (HTMLParser,HTMLParseError)
ImportError: cannot import name 'HTMLParseError'

Comment: Try upgrading bs4 using `pip3 install --upgrade beautifulsoup4

`